# Get timezone offset and display C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, textbox, timezone

I need to get the current timezone offset of the machine my program is running on and display it in a textbox or label.

This is the code I have

```
var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Comment: You can simply do `var x = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;`  is that your question?

Comment: It needs to be the UTC offset so it gets the DST as well. Your code also drops an eror `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'string'` when `var x = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset; textBox1.Text = x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted for obtaining the offset is correct:

```
var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Equally valid would be:

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;
```

The result of either of these is the current local offset, expressed as a `TimeSpan`.  The only part you're missing is how to format it as a `string` for display.  Though there are several options, I recommend a value such as `"+05:30"` or `"-08:00"`.

```
string sign = offset < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "+";
string output = sign + offset.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

You can then assign the `output` string to your label value.

Just for fun, if you'd like to explore how to do the same task with [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), you could write this instead:

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
ZonedDateTime local = now.InZone(tz);
Offset offset = local.Offset;
string output = offset.ToString("m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourTextBoxName.Text = offset.TotalHours.ToString();
```

Comment: Many offsets are not in terms of whole hours.  As an example, this would return `"-5.5"` for India.

Comment: @MattJohnson TotalHours returns a [System.Double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DavidCarrigan - Yes, and then ToString is called on the double.  Your point?

Comment: @MattJohnson My apologies, it appears I may have misunderstood your comment. I thought you were implying this handles only whole hours but the desired result is to include the tenths. It was one of those "long deployment" nights :-/ apologies again.